# Align the non-paranted objects using js (responsive webite)

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, alignment

Here's an example of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: example of what I am trying to achieve]

Hello everyone. So I made a vertical timeline/roadmap with interactive progress bar on scroll. Now I am trying to make my website adaptive for different devices and that's where I encountered a problem. Positioning of every stage changes a lot depending on the screen size, together with its height and milestone indicator position. I tried to write down in CSS with `@media` and `screen` the main screen sizes but even 20px difference in width makes it not aligned. those circles are in SVG in order to create a `clip-path` for my progress bar. I tried to write a script to declare the top border of each stage and align the milestone indicator accordingly but it doesn't seem to work. I would very much appreciate any corrections or suggestions regarding my solution as I am not very familiar with JavaScript.

This is my SVG:

```html
<svg height="1650" width="40" class="loader" style=" z-index:4">
    <rect class="rect1" x="15" y="0" width="10" height="1650" rx="5" ry="5" style="fill:#022c3a;"/>
    <circle class="c1" cx="20" cy="90" r="10" stroke="#022c3a" stroke-width="10" fill="none"/>
    <circle class="c2" cx="20" cy="455" r="10" stroke="#022c3a" stroke-width="10" fill="none"/>
    <circle class="c3" cx="20" cy="800" r="10" stroke="#022c3a" stroke-width="10" fill="none"/>
    <circle class="c4" cx="20" cy="1105" r="10" stroke="#022c3a" stroke-width="10" fill="none"/>
    <circle class="c5" cx="20" cy="1475" r="10" stroke="#022c3a" stroke-width="10" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

This is my attempt in JavaScript:

```js
var stage1 =  document.getElementById("stage1");
var stage2 =  document.getElementById("stage2");
var stage3 =  document.getElementById("stage3");
var stage4 =  document.getElementById("stage4");
var stage5 =  document.getElementById("stage5");
var road = document.getElementById("road_text");
var rec = document.getElementsByClassName("rect1");

window.onload = function() {
    let st1 = stage1.getBoundingClientRect().y,
        st2 = stage2.getBoundingClientRect().y,
        st3 = stage3.getBoundingClientRect().y,
        st4 = stage4.getBoundingClientRect().y,
        st5 = stage5.getBoundingClientRect().y,
        height = road.getBoundingClientRect().height,
        curH = rec.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    if (curH < height | curH > height) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("c1").style.cy = st1;
        document.getElementsByClassName("c2").style.cy = st2;
        document.getElementsByClassName("c3").style.cy = st3;
        document.getElementsByClassName("c4").style.cy = st4;
        document.getElementsByClassName("c5").style.cy = st5;
    }
}
```

Let me know if there is anything else I can add.

my solution

```
window.onload = function() {
var stage1 =  document.getElementById("stage1");
var stage2 =  document.getElementById("stage2");
var stage3 =  document.getElementById("stage3");
var stage4 =  document.getElementById("stage4");
var road = document.getElementById("road_text");
var rec = document.getElementById("rect1");
var recBG = document.getElementById("rect1_bg");
var CW = document.getElementById("c_wrap");
var DW = document.getElementById("d_wrap");

function Resize() {
let st1 = stage1.getBoundingClientRect().height,
    st2 = stage2.getBoundingClientRect().height,
    st3 = stage3.getBoundingClientRect().height,
    st4 = stage4.getBoundingClientRect().height,
    height = road.getBoundingClientRect().height,
    a = document.getElementById("a").getBoundingClientRect().height;

if (height > 0) {
    rec.style.height = height -20;
    CW.style.height = height -20;
    DW.style.height = height -20;
    recBG.style.height = height -20;


    document.getElementById("c1").setAttribute("cy", 110+a);
    document.getElementById("c2").setAttribute("cy", 110+st1+a);
    document.getElementById("c3").setAttribute("cy", 110+st1+st2+a);
    document.getElementById("c4").setAttribute("cy", 110+st1+st2+st3+a);
    document.getElementById("c5").setAttribute("cy", 110+st1+st2+st3+st4+a);

    document.getElementById("c1_bg").setAttribute("cy", 110 + a);
    document.getElementById("c2_bg").setAttribute("cy", 110+st1+a);
    document.getElementById("c3_bg").setAttribute("cy", 110+st1+st2+a);
    document.getElementById("c4_bg").setAttribute("cy", 110+st1+st2+st3+a);
    document.getElementById("c5_bg").setAttribute("cy", 110+st1+st2+st3+st4+a);

    document.getElementById("d1").setAttribute("y", 102.5+a);
    document.getElementById("d2").setAttribute("y", 102.5+st1+a);
    document.getElementById("d3").setAttribute("y", 102.5+st1+st2+a);
    document.getElementById("d4").setAttribute("y", 102.5+st1+st2+st3+a);
    document.getElementById("d5").setAttribute("y", 102.5+st1+st2+st3+st4+a);
    
}
```

}

Resize();
}

Comment: Probably my explanation of the problem wasn't really clear, I apologize for that. But for all those who understood I think I found a solution! If anyone will ever need it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use this example as a starting point. The green line and circles are made with SVG and is part of the CSS. Both the line and circles are placed in the middle of the containing box.

It should be responsive. I use flex box and percentages.

```css
div.left,
div.right {
  display: flex;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMjAiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDIgMiI+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iMSIgY3k9IjEiIHI9IjEiIGZpbGw9ImdyZWVuIi8+PC9zdmc+');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
}

div.right {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

div.right {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

div.left>div {
  width: 48%;
  border: black solid thin;
  height: 80px;
}

div.right>div {
  width: 48%;
  border: solid thin black;
  height: 100px;
}

div.container {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMTAiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSI+PHJlY3Qgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0iZ3JlZW4iLz48L3N2Zz4=');
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-position: center 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div>Text to the left</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div>Text to the right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="left">
    <div>Text to the left</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div>Text to the right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="left">
    <div>Text to the left</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think it would work If I didnt have animation of the clippath and the circles, which change once reached. It is a very good alternative, but didn't fit my needs unfortunately. Or maybe my knowledge isn't enought to adapt it for my website :)

Comment: @OlgaOfferlin you are right. When applying SVG using CSS you cannot have animations and interactivity in the SVG. I will keep my answer as it is and maybe post another answer if I come up with a good solution.